# add and remove class which is within menu but page link is not loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

The class gets toggled when clicking on the menu, but it does not go to the page link when clicked on the menu link; the page is not loaded.

```
<script>
    $(".nav li a").on("click", function () {
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
    <li class=""><a href="/" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/for-buyers" class="">
            test
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/for-sellers" class="active">
            test1
        </a>
    </li>      
</ul>
```

I know I am missing something.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems like that will work fine.because it is working for me.
if not please check your href value @url location